# Epson ePos sdk error when printing from TM-P60II

Tags: ios, printing, bluetooth, epson

I'm using the epson ePOS sdk to print to a TM-P60II from iOS.  I can connect and print, but only once or twice.  I get a timeout error after a try or two, then have to restart the app in order to print again.  I've duplicated the error with their example in the sdk, and in the example on p37 in their manual.  Looks like some kind of bug when closing/releasing the printer.  I've asked their tech support for help but 1 month and 4 emails later and no reply.  (Actually the front line support is good.  2nd tier is the problem.)

My question is, has anyone experienced this and developed a work-around?  I'm considering trying the Zebra iMZ220 instead (comments on that move appreciated), but I'm 90% of the way there and would prefer not to start from scratch.

Thanks!

Here's what the p37 sample looks like:

UPDATE:  Was contacted by Epson, turns out this is a known bug with iOS 7.1.  No word yet on a fix.

UPDATE2: New sdk out... still doesn't work.  However, if you launch it in a separate queue that seems to take care of the problem.  When the queue is auto released the non-released printer item goes with it.  Better practice anyway providing I haven't just created a memory leak.

UPDATE3: See below for code.  Yes it's not polished.  Note that PrinterUtils is just my wrapper around the epson print functions.  Any comments welcome and HTH.

```
id builder2 = [[EposBuilder alloc] initWithPrinterModel: @"TM-P60II" Lang: EPOS_OC_MODEL_ANK];
if (builder2 != nil) {
    errorStatus = EPOS_OC_SUCCESS;

    //Create a print document
    errorStatus = [builder2 addText: @"Hello,\t"];
    errorStatus = [builder2 addText: @"World!\n"];
    errorStatus = [builder2 addCut: EPOS_OC_CUT_FEED];

    //Initialize an EposBuilder class instance for confirmation
    id conBuilder2 = [[EposBuilder alloc] initWithPrinterModel: @"TM-P60II" Lang: EPOS_OC_MODEL_ANK];

    //Initialize an EposPrint class instance
    id printer2 = [[EposPrint alloc] init];
    unsigned long status;
    int connectionType = EPOS_OC_DEVTYPE_BLUETOOTH;
    if (printer2 != nil) {
        //<Start communication with the printer>
        errorStatus = [printer2 openPrinter:connectionType DeviceName:macAddress Enabled:EPOS_OC_FALSE Interval:EPOS_OC_PARAM_DEFAULT];

        //Send Data for confirmation
        errorStatus = [printer2 sendData:conBuilder2 Timeout:10000 Status:&status];

        if ((errorStatus = EPOS_OC_SUCCESS && (status & EPOS_OC_ST_OFF_LINE ) != EPOS_OC_ST_OFF_LINE) ) {
            //<Send print data>
            errorStatus = [printer2 sendData:builder2 Timeout:10000 Status:&status]; }

        //<End communication with the printer>
        errorStatus = [printer2 closePrinter];
    }
}
```

//------- Workaround --------

```
// Busy Spinner
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.center = CGPointMake (self.view.bounds.size.width * 0.5F, self.view.bounds.size.height * 0.5F);
spinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
[self.view addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
spinner.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);

// Launch new queue
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Sync Queue",NULL);
dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
    PrinterUtils *pu = [[PrinterUtils alloc] init];
    EposBuilder *builder = [pu getNewEposBuilder];
    EposPrint *printer = [pu getNewEposPrinter];
    [pu setPrintStyle:PRINTSTYLE_BODY2 eposBuilder:builder];
    [pu loadTextLine:@"bm print to tm-p60II" eposBuilder:builder];
    [pu print:builder eposPrint:printer ];
    [pu closePrinterConnection];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // Update the UI
        [spinner stopAnimating];
    });
});
```

Comment: Omg I have been banging my head against a wall all day over this. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Has anyone come up with a solution yet? We are working with Epson to solve this issue, but have not heard back from them yet.

Comment: Okay, saw the send update. I'm going to try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too on my P60II and eventually called Epson about this. The first level support  sent me to the second level who said they had a firmware update. I went through and filled out a form they emailed me and had the firmware in about 30 mins. The update seems to have corrected the issue. The number I called was (562) 276-1314 and I selected developer support.

Comment: There is already a working solution for this problem, you shouldn't post anecdotes if you had a similar problem. Please read SO's help page on how to ask questions. :-)

Comment: @JoJoe Posting that a firmware update solved the problem is not an "anecdote". It's useful information others might benefit from, and Paul even went to the trouble of including the phone number. IMHO it is people like you who ruin Stack Overflow for the rest of us.